# Lightbox scroll page down on iPhone

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I have portfolio gallery with lightbox viewer. All works fine, but there is a problem on iPhone. After click on image lightbox opens on the bottom of the page. I need to scroll down to see it. Problem is only on iPhone, on other mobile devices it is ok. Tested on Safari and Chrome.

Comment: use this .mfp-wrap {
    z-index: 20000;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

Comment: @VarshaDhadge It seems to be ok. Thanks for your help.